# Ошибка TS2339: Property 'styleSheet' does not exist on type 'HTMLStyleElement'

Tags: typescript

```
    var css = '@page { size: landscape; }',
        head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
        style = document.createElement('style');

    style.type = 'text/css';
    style.media = 'print';

    if (style.styleSheet) {
        style.styleSheet.cssText = css;
    } else {
        style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
    }

    head.appendChild(style);
Ругается на styleSheet
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Встроенный тип **HTMLStyleElement** вашей версии TypeScript не содержит информации об особенностях IE8 и ниже.

Вы можете создать свой уточненный тип, доопределить недостающие свойства и указать тип явно:

```
type IE8HTMLStyleElement = HTMLStyleElement & {styleSheet?: {cssText: string}};   
var style: IE8HTMLStyleElement = document.createElement('style');
```

Comment: style.styleSheet - эхо далекого прошлого :)

Скорее всего вам не нужна эта ветвь проверки. Вы уверены, что что ваша сборка  готовит <IE8 совместимый код?)